# How can I connect to sockJS from a client written in Go?

Tags: go, websocket, sockjs

I have a server that uses websockets. It is written in Go. For testing, I have another application written in Go. To test, I start the server, then run the test client. The test client creates websocket connections to the server and does things (basically impersonating user activity). Both the client and the server are using the gorilla/websockets library, and standard browsers also work fine with the server.

This was all working beautifully.

To support non-compliant browsers, I was asked to start using the [SockJS](https://github.com/igm/sockjs-go/) Go server library. I did this and the new version works just fine when used from a browser by clients using the [SockJS](http://sockjs.org) library.

Now for the problem. SockJS does *not* accept incoming websocket connections. Only connections from the SockJS client. So my testing application doesn't work, and I'm unable to test.

I could recover the old version of my connection code from git and make a separate connection type that uses gorilla/websockets and have my server listen on an additional port that only listens on localhost. This would allow me to test the functionality. The downside is that I have to maintain two versions of essentially the same code, and I wouldn't be testing the real user experience and possibly not find bugs until production.

Ideally the SockJS server, considering it still *uses* gorilla/websockets as a dependency would automatically accept proper websocket connections, but barring that it seems I'd need a SockJS client library in Go which, as far as I can tell, doesn't exist.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: "To support non-compliant browsers" which one ?

Comment: Yandry: I don't know. I think it's just a fallback to support whatever we have to support. It's a very popular public site, so we probably get every browser possible, on every desktop and mobile OS possible.

Comment: In the far future, but it looks like there are now a couple SockJS Go client libraries, mainly [third-light/sockjs-go-client](https://github.com/third-light/sockjs-go-client)